# Match records from two tables that have multiple identical records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I need to verify/match records that match exactly based on criteria. In some cases there can be two identical records in the same table that match to two records in the second table. The problem I'm having is getting the distinct recordID from the first table to match it with the corresponding record in the second table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ID, 
AMT.ID, 
AMT.VerifiedSalesRecordID AS MatchID, 
AMT.ProductID
FROM AccountManagerTracker AS AMT JOIN Sales AS s
ON CHECKSUM (AMT.CompanyID, 
AMT.DateFulfilled, 
AMT.ProductID, 
AMT.GrossSalesAmount, 
AMT.NetSalesAmount, 
DATEPART(MM,AMT.CommissionMonth)) = CHECKSUM(s.CompanyID, 
s.DateFulfilled, 
s.ProductID, 
s.GrossSalesAmount, 
s.NetSalesAmount, 
DATEPART(MM,s.CommissionMonth))
WHERE s.ProductID IN (1,2,3,38)
AND AMT.VerifiedSalesRecordID IS NULL
```

Results:

```
T1ID  T2ID MatchID ProductID
14777   1   NULL    1
14813   2   NULL    1
14825   4   NULL    1
14933   6   NULL    3
14948   13  NULL    1
14948   14  NULL    1
15029   19  NULL    2
15043   17  NULL    2
15058   18  NULL    2
15151   22  NULL    1
15154   20  NULL    1
15156   25  NULL    2
15328   33  NULL    2
15330   30  NULL    1
15330   31  NULL    1
```

I only want distinct records from T1. Any ideas?

**Edit**

`15330   30  NULL    1
15330   31  NULL    1`

These two rows are the problem. It trys to verify the same record of Table 1 with two different records of Table 2.

Comment: Your results don't match the query -- What is `MatchID` ?  Why are you using `CHECKSUM()` instead of just join on the columns themselves?  Was this deliberate?  What is your expected output?

Comment: In this example what needs  to selected highest or lowest T2ID : `14948   13  NULL    1
14948   14  NULL    1` ?

Comment: MatchID is VerifiedSalesRecordID. If I do the join on the columns I get the same end result. If there are multiple identical records then I want identical record A from Table 1 to match with identical record A from Table 2 until all of the multiple identical records have been matched with a unique id from table 1.

Comment: The inclusion of the T2Id column is creating a distinct record for each ID in T1...ie, 14948 shows twice becaus the T2Id is different bertween the records.  What you want to do is GROUP By on T1ID, ProductID and remove the T2ID.

Comment: @MikeTWebb I still need to retrieve T2 ID in order to update the record in T2 with T1 ID. How would I retrieve that or how would you suggest updating the T2 record?

Comment: @Cal...so you want to update T2Id to equal T1Id...ie, T2Id 13 becomes 14948?  And T2Id  14 would become 14948?

Comment: @MikeTWebb I need to update T2.VerifiedSalesRecordID = T1.ID

Comment: @Cal...ah gotcha.  Always good to know the requirement.  Then you're almost there.  Your result set has the data you need.  I'll put an example in an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better solution to the problem. I needed record 1 of table a to match with record 1 of table b and record 2 with record 2 etc. Here is the solution I was finally able to come up with.

`UPDATE Table1
SET VerifiedSalesRecordID = t2.ID
FROM
(SELECT AMT.AMID, AMT.CompanyID, AMT.DateFulfilled, AMT.ProductID, AMT.GrossSalesAmount, AMT.NetSalesAmount, AMT.CommissionMonth, AMT.ID, AMT.VerifiedSalesRecordID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AMT.AMID, AMT.CompanyID, AMT.ProductID, AMT.DateFulfilled ORDER BY AMT.CompanyID) AS RecordNum
FROM Table1 AS AMT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT AMID, CompanyID, DateFulfilled, ProductID, GrossSalesAmount, NetSalesAmount, COUNT(*) AS DupCount
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY AMID, CompanyID, DateFulfilled, ProductID, GrossSalesAmount, NetSalesAmount
) AS Dup ON AMT.AMID = Dup.AMID AND AMT.CompanyID = Dup.CompanyID AND AMT.DateFulfilled = Dup.DateFulfilled AND AMT.ProductID = Dup.ProductID AND AMT.GrossSalesAmount = Dup.GrossSalesAmount) AS t1
JOIN
(SELECT s.SalesRepID, s.CompanyID, s.DateFulfilled, s.ProductID, s.GrossSalesAmount, s.NetSalesAmount, s.CommissionMonth, s.ID, s.Verified, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.SalesRepID, s.CompanyID, s.ProductID, s.DateFulfilled ORDER BY s.CompanyID) AS RecordNum
FROM Table2 AS s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SalesRepID, CompanyID, DateFulfilled, ProductID, GrossSalesAmount, NetSalesAmount, COUNT(*) AS DupCount
    FROM Table2
    WHERE SalesTypeID = 2
    GROUP BY SalesRepID, CompanyID, DateFulfilled, ProductID, GrossSalesAmount, NetSalesAmount
) AS Dup ON s.SalesRepID = Dup.SalesRepID AND s.CompanyID = Dup.CompanyID AND s.DateFulfilled = Dup.DateFulfilled AND s.ProductID = Dup.ProductID AND s.GrossSalesAmount = Dup.GrossSalesAmount) AS t2
ON t1.AMID = t2.SalesRepID AND t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID AND t1.DateFulfilled = t2.DateFulfilled
    AND t1.ProductID = (CASE WHEN t2.ProductID = 38 THEN t1.ProductID ELSE t2.ProductID END) AND t1.NetSalesAmount = t2.NetSalesAmount AND (CASE WHEN t1.ProductID = 3 THEN t2.GrossSalesAmount ELSE t1.GrossSalesAmount END) = t2.GrossSalesAmount AND DATEPART(MM,t1.CommissionMonth) = DATEPART(MM, t2.CommissionMonth) AND t1.RecordNum = t2.RecordNum
WHERE Table1.ID = t1.ID AND t1.VerifiedSalesRecordID IS NULL AND t2.Verified = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE AccountManagerTracker SET VerifiedSalesRecordID = (
SELECT s.ID 
FROM AccountManagerTracker JOIN Sales AS s
ON CHECKSUM (AccountManagerTracker .CompanyID, 
AccountManagerTracker .DateFulfilled, 
AccountManagerTracker .ProductID, 
AccountManagerTracker .GrossSalesAmount, 
AccountManagerTracker .NetSalesAmount, 
DATEPART(MM,AMT.CommissionMonth)) = CHECKSUM(s.CompanyID, 
s.DateFulfilled, 
s.ProductID, 
s.GrossSalesAmount, 
s.NetSalesAmount, 
DATEPART(MM,s.CommissionMonth))
WHERE s.ProductID IN (1,2,3,38)
AND AccountManagerTracker.VerifiedSalesRecordID IS NULL
)
```

Your FROM and your JOIN are getting you the right data.  And you can see by the result set that the data is what you want.  Since you have th correct s.ID, you can update the VerifiedSalesRecordID column.

If you're using SQL Server, be sure to Use BEGIN TRANSACTION prior to the UPDATE call....this will leve the data in and un-Committed state so you can verify the results of the UPDATE wothout Committing the result to the Database